# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException:

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have been facing a issue, when I'm trying to run a hive query to insert data into a Hive External Table. The process fails at reduce.

The diagnostic console messages are as follows:

```
    Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_201709171147_0059_r_000005

URL:
  http://localhost:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201709171147_0059&tipid=task_201709171147_0059_r_000005
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-gms/hive_2017-09-17_15-05-39_454_6420114297268603231/_task_tmp.-mr-10007/_tmp.000005_3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-gms/hive_2017-09-17_15-05-39_454_6420114297268603231/_task_tmp.-mr-10007/_tmp.000005_3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:1061)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.flush(GroupByOperator.java:1027)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processHashAggr(GroupByOperator.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processKey(GroupByOperator.java:751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processOp(GroupByOperator.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.createForwardJoinObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.checkAndGenObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:851)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinOperator.endGroup(JoinOperator.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:200)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-gms/hive_2017-09-17_15-05-39_454_6420114297268603231/_task_tmp.-mr-10007/_tmp.000005_3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at $Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at $Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 60  Reduce: 16   Cumulative CPU: 1488.73 sec   HDFS Read: 15611147485 HDFS Write: 6697774964 SUCCESS
Job 1: Map: 41  Reduce: 11   Cumulative CPU: 2231.76 sec   HDFS Read: 10853652873 HDFS Write: 8893984114 SUCCESS
Job 2: Map: 31  Reduce: 10   Cumulative CPU: 2426.38 sec   HDFS Read: 9165529191 HDFS Write: 8927047843 SUCCESS
Job 3: Map: 33  Reduce: 10   Cumulative CPU: 2469.67 sec   HDFS Read: 9198570523 HDFS Write: 9003617537 SUCCESS
Job 4: Map: 33  Reduce: 10   Cumulative CPU: 2519.58 sec   HDFS Read: 9275146392 HDFS Write: 9032825573 SUCCESS
Job 5: Map: 33  Reduce: 10   Cumulative CPU: 2607.76 sec   HDFS Read: 9304360085 HDFS Write: 9107047528 SUCCESS
Job 6: Map: 34  Reduce: 10   Cumulative CPU: 2624.55 sec   HDFS Read: 9378577538 HDFS Write: 15269385865 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 days 4 hours 32 minutes 48 seconds 430 msec
```

The Log Messages from the Jobtracker web-ui are as follows:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-gms/hive_2017-09-17_15-05-39_454_6420114297268603231/_task_tmp.-mr-10007/_tmp.000004_0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-gms/hive_2017-09-17_15-05-39_454_6420114297268603231/_task_tmp.-mr-10007/_tmp.000004_0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:1061)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processAggr(GroupByOperator.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processKey(GroupByOperator.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processOp(GroupByOperator.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.createForwardJoinObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.checkAndGenObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:851)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinOperator.endGroup(JoinOperator.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:200)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hive-gms/hive_2017-09-17_15-05-39_454_6420114297268603231/_task_tmp.-mr-10007/_tmp.000004_0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at $Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at $Proxy2.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)

    Last 4KB
Last 8KB
All
attempt_201709171147_0059_r_000005_0    task_201709171147_0059_r_000005 gmdatal01-p1.ilcb.tcprod.local  FAILED
```

I have set the dynamic partitions for hive:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partitions = true
set hive.exec.dynamic.partitions.mode = nonstrict
```

I have also formated the namenode and have tried it again but the error wouldn't go of.

Comment: Hi Sakthi. Please make an effort when posting questions to add a formatted block around logs and so forth. The original post was not very readable, and it would have been easily missed that you'd supplied two log files.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

The root cause of the issue seems space related. I was using a query that joins several large tables, as the data is skewed, Hive began to make big temporary table, for which there was not space on the disk. I reverted the configuration files to default and compressed intermediate results (configuration files) to get the result.

Comment: That's weird, because I am doing an insert of a 4 gb dataset into a 100 gb HDFS instance and get this error.